# Appending separate rows from csv in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to append separate rows from a csv file. I want to append the first, third, fourth, and fifth element. Here is what I have so far but it doesn't seem to work — any ideas? This code currently saves into two separate lists; I want the rows to be appended into the same list.

```
import csv
game_file = open(gamefile + ".csv")
game_file = []
score_file.append([row[0]])
score_file.append([row[2:5]])
with open(studentsclass + ".csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(score_file)
        f.close()
    game_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `csv` could help:

```
import csv

game_file = []
included_cols = [0, 2, 3, 4, 5]

with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        game_file.append(list(row[i] for i in included_cols))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use enumerate on your `reader` object and check if the index is in your desired list (which I have converted it to set that has O(1) for check membership ):

```
import csv

temp=0
rows=[]
with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
     for i,row in enumerate(spamreader):
             if i in {0,2,3,4,5}:
                temp+=1
                rows.append(row)
             if temp==5:
                   print rows
                   break
```